# Copy gitignored files from host A to host B (rsync?)

Tags: rsync, git, scp, file-transfer

I have a git repo where several files containing sensitive info are gitignored. These files are located in various subdirectories at various depths.

Host **A** has all these files in place. I've cloned the repo onto host **B**, and am looking for a good way to copy the gitignored files from host **A**.

I have SSH access from **A** to **B**, and I suspect there's a way I could do this with rsync, but all the examples I've found describe doing the opposite: syncing everything *except* the gitignored files.

Comment: so you want to sync ONLY gitignored, not just sync everything? *examples I've found describe doing the opposite* I imagine that could be modified to do the inverse, can you link an example you've found

Answer (score 0):

Using `git check-ignore **/*` in the git project directory would get all the files ignored by git.

You should send the output from the git command to a file and use the option `--files-from` from the `rsync` command. For example:

```bash
git check-ignore **/* > ignoredFiles
rsync -a --files-from=./ignoredFiles . host:/path/to/ignoredFiles
```

You have to specify the dot `.` in `rsync` (after the **ignoredFiles** file) since this represents the source directory which would be the root of your git project.

---

The command `git check-ignore **/*` only worked for me in `zsh` (I'm not sure why in bash it did not work). However using that command will not work for hidden files, so if you want to exclude hidden files too you could use:

```bash
find . -exec git check-ignore {} + > ignoredFiles
rsync -a --files-from=./ignoredFiles . host:/path/to/ignoredFiles
```

Redirecting the ignored files to some file and read them with --files-from seems to be safe since filenames with spaces are copied correctly (but I'm not sure about other special filenames).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, though I had to adjust the `find` command to exclude files in the `.git` directory (it was picking up `./.git/refs/tags` otherwise): `find . -not -path './.git/*' -exec git check-ignore {} + > ignoredFiles`. I also added the `--no-links` flag to the `rsync` call because I wanted to skip simlinks.

I ended up taking a different approach though, so I'll post that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using rsync, and rather than trying to enumerate all the gitignored files, I synced the entire directory, excluding .git/, and used `--ignore-existing` to avoid syncing the files that were already present in the destination:

```bash
rsync -avz --no-links --ignore-existing --exclude='.git/' \
    ~/example/repo user@host:example
```

I also found rsync's `--dry-run` option very useful in combination with `-vv` to test the `rsync` invocation and make sure it would sync the files I wanted,

```bash
rsync --dry-run -avvz ...
```